# Why is css not applied on paginated query?

Tags: css

I have a `WP_Query` for which, when paginated, css specific to the 'last-of-type' is not applied.

My flawed thinking is that in addition to the entry which is genuinely last, pagination causes some preceding entries to also temporarily become last-of-type... as the final item on each page, and hence last-of-type will apply to whichever entry is last on each paginated page.

But it doesn't, and is applied only to that which is genuinely last.

My limited knowledge of 'inspect element' shows that the css is applied when unpaginated, but not when paginated.

UPDATE: I don't think this is a pure-css issue, and is about what WP does in this instance by pagination which stops the css applying - because if I move a close-div tag the css is applied.

Comment: Hello Gulliver! This is a pure CSS question, but if you give me a link I can detect the problem quickly before this question gets another 4 close votes.

Comment: @Jack Johansson ... thanks. I don't think it's a pure-css issue, and is about what WP does in this instance by pagination which stops site-wide css applying. :-)